# Slick Carousel Not formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slick.js

I'm trying to get four photos to automatically play through on the carousel but Slick isn't formatting the photos or anything. Could someone show me what I am doing wrong and what I can do to fix it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.css"/>

<style>
photo-show {
 width: 40%;
}
</style>


</head>

<body>

<div class="photo-show">
<div><img src="./src/cat1.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div><img src="./src/cat2.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div><img src="./src/cat3.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div><img src="./src/cat4.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.photo-show').slick({
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,
      });
    });
</script>


</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "formatting the photos or anything"

Comment: How do you want the photos formatted?  Are the loading or showing broken images?

Answer (score 1):

Making a guess here, it looks like you are trying to apply a style to your Slick photos.  Your CSS is wrong and wouldn't format any of your images.

Try this CSS instead:

```
<style>
.photo-show img {
    width: 40%;
}
</style>
```

Notice that I added a "." before `photo-show` and specific `img` so that you can stylize your images within your `photo-show` container.